# Async function printing empty value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I call my function "randomChat" it somehow returns an empty value, which should not happen with my code.

randomChat Function:

```
    Future<String> randomChat(String userId) async {
  String roomId = await connectRoom(userId);
  return roomId;
}
```

connectRoom Function:

```
   Future<String> connectRoom(String userId) async {
  List<String> connectedUsers = await getChattingWith(userId);
  late String roomId;

  // Find all the rooms where userId2 is empty
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('rooms')
      .where('userId2', isEqualTo: "")
      .where("userId1", isNotEqualTo: userId)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) async {
    // If no empty room is found, create room
    if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
      print("call empty");
      String roomId = await createRoom(userId);
      return roomId;
    }

//        // If an empty room which is not connected to userId (part of connectedUsers) is found, connect to it
    for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.docs.length; i++) {
      var data = snapshot.docs[i].data();
      Room room = Room.fromJson(data);
// check if the empty room found is not connected to userId
      bool found = connectedUsers.contains(room.userId1);

      if (!found) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('rooms')
            .doc(room.id)
            .update({"userId2": userId});
        print("call not found = $roomId");
        return roomId = room.id;
      } else {
        
        roomId = await createRoom(userId);
        print("call found = $roomId");
        return roomId;
      }
    }
  });
  print("call nothing = $roomId");
  return roomId;
}
```

And here I am calling the function and printing the value (which is empty, but should not be empty. It should return my roomId):

```
   onPressed: () async {
                String roomId = await randomChat(uid);
                print(roomId);
     
              },
```

Create Room function (where I also correctly get the roomId printed):

```
    Future<String> createRoom(String userId) async {
  DocumentReference docRef =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("rooms").add({
    "userId1": userId,
    "userId2": "",
    "created_at": DateTime.now().toString(),
  });
  await docRef.update({"roomId": docRef.id});
  print("create room: ${docRef.id}");
  return docRef.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `connectRoom`, you need to `await` for `FirebaseFirestore` result:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('rooms')
      .where('userId2', isEqualTo: "")
      .where("userId1", isNotEqualTo: userId)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) async {
  ...
}
```

also you define new `String roomId` in every if statement inside `then` function, just pass that value to your main `roomId` which is define as `late String roomId`.

Comment: That did not fix it, sadly. I still get the error that the roomId was not initialized. Even though the createRoom function is called and returning a roomId.

Comment: you said if you print roomId exactly before `return roomId;` inside `randomChat ` that would show its value?

Comment: No, but my createRoom function (which is called, since the conditions of the if statements are met) is returning a roomId and also printing it.

Comment: could you add the print code to your question so I see where do you have it?

Comment: Just added it. Thank you for being so helpful!

Comment: @cipano I just updated you question and add some print, could you run that and tell me the result?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minute.

Comment: Okay, just added the print statements. It prints "call empty".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248999/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-cipano).

Comment: Also just one more note: It prints "call empty" before "create room".